# Select query with custom column and value of other column

Tags: mysql, query

I want to have a query that have a custom column and have some value of other column

here is example of a table

```
table 1 : id, name, emp_id
```

I want to have input like this

```
id | name | emp_id | proccess    |
1  | John | 002    | Work of John|
```

The process is just costum column I want to do it in Select query..

**This is what I tried:**

```
Select id, name, emp_id, "Work of "+name as process, from table1
```

But its not working. I also want to add 2 or more column value in custom column.

Thanks

Comment: See `JOIN` and `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Suggest you either self-answer (and provide others with the solution and get some points), or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer Is Concat

You can use concat to combine an array and value of column

example query:

`Select id, name, emp_id, concat("Work of ", name) as process, from table1`